# Until loop not terminating or holding incremented variable's value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, until-loop

Why is this loop not breaking(ending due to `if` statement) or using the newly incremented value of `$c` variable? Tried **c=expr $c + 1** with and without `"` double quote.

```
export c=1; ssh auser@someserver "until [[ 1 -eq 2 ]]; do echo \"Value of 'c' == $c\"; c=`expr $c + 1`; echo \"$c - Incremented value: `expr $c + 1`\"; if [[ $c -gt 5 ]]; then break; fi; sleep 2 ; done;"
```

or

```
$ export c=1; ssh root@$CHEF_SERVER \
> "until [[ 1 -eq 2 ]]; do \
>   echo \"Value of 'c' == $c\"; c=`expr $c + 1`; \
>   echo \"$c - Incremented value: `expr $c + 1`\"; \
>   if [[ $c -gt 5 ]]; then break; fi; \
>   sleep 2; \
>   echo; \
> done;"
```

Output is infinte: I had to ^c it.

```
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Value of 'c' == 1
1 - Incremented value: 2
Killed by signal 2.
```

Comment: Can you split the code up onto multiple lines? It's really difficult to read.

Comment: John, condition in `until` is intentional. I want that to run infinite. But I want the if statement to work and `break` the shenzi (issue I'm getting in Production :) ).

Comment: not a bash guru, but I'd assume that the `break` would only apply to the current `do` and the `until` would just run it again.

Comment: @lecstor I see only one loop `until` here (either `for`, `while` or `until` etc loops use `do` and `done`) in BASH / Shell to start and end it's scope/boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that shell variables needs to be properly *escaped* before using them in conditionals or assignments inside `ssh` under double quotes. Not doing so will let the variables expand even before the commands are executed over the remote machine. So in your case, no matter if you increment `c` or not the variable is expanded and condition remains always as below in the remote machine.

```
if [[ 1 -gt 5 ]]; then
    break
fi
```

Also `expr` is pretty much outdated, use a traditional C style loop increment using `((..))` as and escape all the invocations of variable inside to defer the variable expansion

```
ssh root@$CHEF_SERVER "
until [[ 1 -eq 2 ]]; do
    ((c = c+1))
    echo "Incremented value: \$c"
    if [[ \$c -gt 5 ]]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 2
done"
```

Comment: My bad, yes, it worked, was missing `;` after `((c = c+1));`

Comment: My understanding was, we only need to escape a variable like you did, only if it was defined new/fresh within the SSH session. Seems like, that's not true. It's funny that within `(( ))`, we didn't have to escape it.

Comment: @ArunSangal Whether a variable reference gets resolved locally or remotely depends only on syntax, not on where/how it's defined. If it's in double-quotes and it starts with an unescaped `$`, it will be expanded by the local shell before being sent over `ssh`.  The references in `(( ))` aren't resolved locally because they don't start with `$`. Note that variables are *not* shared across the connection; any value assigned to a variable on the local computer (e.g. with `export c=1`) has nothing to do with any variable on the remote system, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are expanded inside double-quoted strings.
So are backticks.

You declare a variable `c` and assign it the value `1`.

You then call `ssh` and pass it a double-quoted string.

The shell invoked by ssh sees:

```
until [[ 1 -eq 2 ]]; do 
   echo "Value of 'c' == 1"; c=2; 
   echo "1 - Incremented value: 2"; 
   if [[ 1 -gt 5 ]]; then break; fi; 
   sleep 2; 
   echo; 
done;
```